# How to check if properties in a JSON file are ordered?

Tags: json, gulp

I have a big json file which is changed quite often (translation values). I need to check whether properties in this json are sorted alphabetically. Perfectly I'd like to use gulp for that and run this check in CI environment so when properties aren't ordered an error is reported.

I've searched for it but haven't found anything. Are you aware of any existing solution dealing with this problem?

Comment: There is normally no need to reorder objects' property mappings in json alphabetically since the order of object variables doesn't matter normally. Perhaps if you explained more why you need this functionality, we might be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that order of properties ultimately doesn't matter. The motivation is to keep json clean, easily readable and, well, in order.

Comment: I can understand your problem, especially for many edits and finding existing translations to check if they already exist. Json wasn't designed with readability in mind. A better solution would be to use a proper database to store your translations, but of course that is a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it purely with node.js and hook it into your gulp build process easily enough:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile("data.json", { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data).mystuff;

    //check if it's ordered
    for (var i = 1; i < dataObj.length; i++) {
        if (dataObj[i].toLowerCase() < dataObj[i-1].toLowerCase()) { //note that depending on what it is you're ordering, this might need to change...
            throw new Error('THIS IS OUT OF ORDER! I TOLD YOU! I TOLD YOU!!!! KEEP IT ORDERED! AND WHAT DID YOU DO?!!! UNACCEPTABLE!!!');
        }
    }
    console.log('Ordered correctly! Good work!');
});
```

And the data.json that I used to test it, ordered incorrectly:

```
{
    "mystuff": [
      "Super",
      "Duper",
      "Happy",
      "Fun"
  ]
}
```

And ordered correctly:

```
{
    "mystuff": [
      "Duper",
      "Fun",
      "Happy",
      "Super"
  ]
}
```

And if you want to take it a step further and have the process automatically re-order the file for you, you could do something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = 'data.json';
var fileOptions = { encoding: 'utf8' };
fs.readFile(fileName, fileOptions, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    debugger;
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    var dataObjOrdered = orderObj(dataObj);
    var jsonOrdered = JSON.stringify(dataObjOrdered, null, 4);
    fs.writeFile(fileName, jsonOrdered, fileOptions, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('JSON data fields are ordered huzzah!');
    });
});

/**
 * Returns an object with the same data, but with its fields ordered.
 * Note that we leave array values in the same order they're already in
 */
function orderObj(obj) {
    if (!isObject(obj)) {
        return obj;
    }

    //arrays are left alone. if you want to order them too, do it inside this block
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj;
    }

    //load up an array containing all our object's fields
    var fields = [];
    for (var field in obj) {
        fields.push(field);
    }

    //sort the fields alphabetically (remember to do this compare case-insensitively since utf-8 capital letters come before lowercase letters)
    fields.sort(function (a, b) {
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    //return the new object with ordered fields, recursively ordering sub objects' fields
    var result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var field = fields[i];
        var value = obj[field];
        result[field] = orderObj(value);
    }
    return result;
}

function isObject(value) {
  // http://jsperf.com/isobject4
  return value !== null && typeof value === 'object';
}
```

Comment: I love the error message but this code seems to check a list of array items rather than object properties.

Comment: haha, gotta have fun with these. Anywho, what's your data's schema--could you add an example of your json data? You can just dot into whatever property you want it ordered by.

Comment: Oh, after reading your comment above, do you want the thing to just order properties by name and write the ordered json back to the file? That'd be fun to write. I'm doin' it. I'll put it in a separate answer or delete my existing one.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to provide code that also writes ordered json back to the file. I put in comments so you can see what the code does, but let me know if you have any questions as to what it does.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed with the effort you put into this. As mentioned the code in the first part of your answer does something different but the further code is close to what I was asking about. Now you sort properties but what I want is to check whether properties are sorted (so it's not far). I've read the code, everything is clear. If there are no ready solutions/packages then maybe I can go further with your code, change it so it's a validator/checker and pack it to gulp task. Thanks, your answer is helpful.

Comment: Cool, man. You could modify the first solution do a forin loop instead and also be recursive if you need to check the order in subobjects.